# log out banned user in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, security, symfony5, easyadmin

How can I log out active session of banned user with Symfony?

**This is not working**

```
security:
    always_authenticate_before_granting: true
```

this is error

```
 The security option "always_authenticate_before_granting" cannot be used when "enable_authenticator_manager" is set to true. If you rely on this behavior, set it to false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    # ...
    enable_authenticator_manager: falstr
```

Comment: not working `Invalid type for path "security.enable_authenticator_manager". Expected "bool", but got "string".
Hint: Enables the new Symfony Security system based on Authenticators, all used authenticators must support this before enabling this.`

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
# config/packages/security.yaml

security:
    always_authenticate_before_granting: true
    enable_authenticator_manager: false
```

Nilesh's answer is right but there is a typo.

Comment: `Custom authenticators are not supported when "security.enable_authenticator_manager" is not set to true.` not working

Comment: The user should be automatically logged out when the authentication token changes, a good way to do this is with roles. Based on the user banned value in your database change that users role in your user entity file. This should cause a logout.